# How to reset a password after the first sign-in using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to implement a password reset after the user signs in for the first time using "[How To: Allow users to edit their password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)" as a reference.

I am getting the following error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/user/update_password"
```

I added the full trace at the end of the post.

What am I missing?

I'm using Rails '4.2.6'.

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :reset_last_captcha_code!
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
      update_password_user_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" } ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="action_container">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Route:

```
  resource :user, only: [:edit] do
    collection do
      patch 'update_password'
    end
  end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Full Trace:

```
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/Users/jj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/Users/jj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/Users/jj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: are you trying to navigate directly to `/user/update_password` in your browser? the tutorial intends for you to put your view code in `user/edit` and go there to have you update your password.

Comment: @eiko in views I created a folder called user and added a edit template.

Comment: and you go to `/user/edit` in your browser to fill out the form, and you get the above-mentioned error upon hitting submit?

Answer (score 0):

Your route is a `PATCH`, but your form is hitting a `GET` endpoint. Try changing the first line in your view to this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" }, :method => patch ) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise it's generally far easier to use what they've implemented unless you've a really good reason for doing otherwise. All you need in your config/routes.rb file is:

```
devise_for :users
```

After you've done that, run rake routes from your terminal and you should see a list of routes for changing registrations, passwords, deleting your account etc.. If you really want to be lazy you can run from your terminal:

```
rails g devise:install views
```

This will give you all the forms and views you need for managing users. Then to link people to the views you just need to use the routes that have been set up for you. Run

```
rake routes
```

And you'll see what route you need to link to. For example a to make a sign in button, link_to new_user_session_path. For a sign up button, it would be link_to new_user_registration_path. The page that that leads to has easy links for resetting your password / deleting your account etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the routes as `devise` recommends it. In the `routes.rb` instead of:

```
  resource :user, only: [:edit] do
    collection do
      patch 'update_password'
    end
  end
```

Use:

```
devise_for :users
```

For more information on how that is converted into Rails routes [check out this documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb)